# Global Variable Not Updating Correctly

Tags: jquery

My global variables aren't updating properly when I attempt the click below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var vote = undefined;
    var more = undefined;
    $(".sme").click(function (event) {
        var vote = $(this).attr('id');
        $(".sme").removeClass('clicked');
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
        $('.tick').fadeTo('fast', 0.8, function () {});
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

[RESOLVED]

Comment: why assigning `undefined`?

Comment: I keep getting an "Undefined" error.

Answer (score 1):

You are again using  `var vote = $(this).attr('id');` inside click event
Replace it with   `vote = $(this).attr('id');`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var vote = undefined;
    var more = undefined;
    $(".sme").click(function (event) {
        vote = $(this).attr('id');
        $(".sme").removeClass('clicked');
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
        $('.tick').fadeTo('fast', 0.8, function () {});
    });
});
```